# get column value with ID as foreign key in recursion

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, common-table-expression

I have created a temp table from recursion (CTE), then left join PARAM_VALUE from another table. My temp table look like this

[image]

I have the BOQ_ITEM_FK which points to ID having the PARAM_VALUE. I want to get the PARAM_VALUE from the parent ID and apply it to the child PARAM_VALUE.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT ID, BRIEF, REFERENCE, PARAM_VALUE
FROM @BOQ_TABLE 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT BOQ_ITEM_FK FROM @BOQ_TABLE)
```

But I only get:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `PARAM_VALUE` from another related row in the same table, you'll need to join the table with itself.

When a query includes the same table multiple times you need to assign an alias to each *table instance*, in order to identify where each column is coming from. I chose the aliases `a` and `b` but you are free to choose any alias that makes sense to you.

Your query could look like:

```
select
  a.id,
  a.brief,
  a.reference,
  b.param_value
from @boq_table a
left join @boq_table b on b.id = a.boq_item_fk
```

Notice that:

- The `PARAM_VALUE` column is coming from the second table instance and, therefore, comes from a different row.
- The query uses an outer join (`LEFT JOIN`) in case the parent row does not exist.